# Is "monthly shipment" a compound noun?

Tags: nouns

I am wondering if "monthly shipment" can be considered a compound noun. I think it cannot, but what made me less certain was having seen "monthly ticket" listed as one in a grammar site.

Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: No, it's two separate words forming a syntactic construction consisting of the noun "shipment" as head and the adjective "monthly" as modifier. Compound words are single words, i.e. morphological compounds, consisting of two smaller bases, e.g. "girlfriend, blacksmith, shirt-sleeve, pub-crawl etc.

Comment: It's not a Noun-Noun compound (often just called "noun compound"); it's an Adjective-Noun compound, which is, as BillJ says, a construction.